# MongoDb geolocation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation

I have collection called community. Community has a geolocation and a radius.
Let's say users wants to join a community then I take his geolocation if available or last saved location from db. And then check if user is in radius of community then allow him to join community.
Only data I have is users location I have to find list of all communities in whose radius this user exist.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data present in `community` and `users` collections? This will help the community members to try out the queries and answer your question in precise manner. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Minimal sample data.
community.name = "Abcd";
community.geolocation =  { type: "Point", coordinates: [] };
community.radius = 10//in km.
user.geolocation =  { type: "Point", coordinates: [] };
both are 2dsphere index.
community have name, geolocation point coordinates, radius.
for user we only have his lng, lat.

Comment: This does not help. Please add 2 or 3 documents from both the collections

Comment: I don't think adding any more data is required. For this query only community name, geolocation point lng& lat, radius is enough data for community collection. And for user just consider we have his lng, lat available to us. Using user's lng, lat query community collection [name, geolocation (lng,lat), radius]. Project is under NDA so cannot disclose any fields.

Answer (score 0):

Answer constructed with help from the official MongoDB Docs present at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/#find-restaurants-with-geospatial-queries) link.

Your query for finding locations within **5 kilometres** should look like this:

```
db.community.find({
  geolocation: {
    { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ uLongitude, uLatitude ], 5 / 6378.1 ] }
    }
  }
})
```

**Explanation:**

- `$geoWithin` looks for locations within the region that is specified
  by its argument
- `$centerSphere` is used to denote a circular region
  by specifying the center and the radius in radians
- `5 / 6378.1` is used to convert 5 kilometers to radians. See [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) page for more information from the official MongoDB docs

The Docs also state:

> $geoWithin does not return the documents in any specific order, so it
>   may show the user the furthest documents first.

To find the documents in a sorted manner use this query which is constructed using docs present at [this location](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/#sorted-with-nearsphere):

```
var METERS_PER_KM = 6378.1
db.community.find({ 
  geolocation: {
    $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ]
      },
      $maxDistance: 5 * METERS_PER_KM
    }
  }
});
```

**Explanation:**

- `$nearSphere` returns documents within the sphere of *radius*(`5 km`)
  from the *center* (`uLongitude`, `uLatitude`) in a sorted manner,
  nearest to furthest from the center.

**Edit 1:**
As per the discussion in comments, going through the MongoDB Docs, you can use an aggregation query like this one to get the distance as well:

```
db.places.aggregate( [
   {
      $geoNear: {
         near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ uLongitude, uLatitude ] },
         spherical: true,
         query: {
           // Pass Any Other Query Conditions in this object
         },
         distanceField: "calcDistance"
      }
   }
] )
```

**Explanation:**
You can pass any other query conditions to the `query` param in the `$geoNear` stage and you should get the distance in the `calcDistance` field in the query result documents. Try following through the examples [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/).

**Edit 2:**
To find community whose sphere range intersects with the user's coords, the community location must be stored as a `Polygon`, unfortunately, this is not true in your case, or else, you can use a simple `$geoIntersect` query. [Link to example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#op._S_geoIntersects)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already implemented same query as a work arround. What above query does is it draws a circle arround user and then find communities in radius of 5km (10km in my case). I don't know the radius of community.